# Getting weekly rate from the sql table

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL table (let's call it A) with the following two columns

```
dt  - date
userid - id of a user
enroll - whether user enrolled or not  (1 if user did, 0 otherwise)
```

It is easy to calculate the percentage of people who clicked on a daily basis, it's just

```
select dt, sum(enroll)/count(*) as pct from A group by dt
```

However, I was wondering if there's a nice in-built function in mysql that calculates such percentages on a weekly, monthly, yearly (or some other customizable date range).

Is there an easy way of doing it?

Comment: There are several functions that would help. For monthly or annual, you can use the MONTH and YEAR functions. For other ranges, you can use the INTERVAL. All easy to google for syntax and examples.

Comment: Why would you store information about users that didn't enrol? I didn't enrol. Am I in there?

Answer (score -1):

You need aggregate functions and a way to determine the month given a particular date.  [`LAST_DAY(datestamp)` gives you midnight](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) on the last day of the month containing any given datestamp.

So, try this.

```
 SELECT LAST_DAY(dt) month_ending,
        sum(enroll)/count(*) as pct
   FROM a
  GROUP BY LAST_DAY(dt)
```

You can do something similar for weeks. But you need a way to group by week, just like `LAST_DAY()` lets you group by month.  I suggest you look that up.